# removeAllFeatures is not a function

Tags: javascript, openlayers

My effort is to remove the already drawn circle in Open Layers map. It's the only vector in the map so I decided to try removing all features as follows:

```
var vectors = map.getLayersByClass('OpenLayers.Layer.Vector');
    vectors.removeAllFeatures();
```

I got the following error:

```
removeAllFeatures is not a function
```

What is my mistake?
Thanks.

Comment: Check if map.getLayersByClass('OpenLayers.Layer.Vector') returns an empty object?  

what does console.log(vectors) show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`removeAllFeatures` is a function of the layer object. `getLayersByClass` returns an array of layers. Try this:

```
var vectors = map.getLayersByClass('OpenLayers.Layer.Vector');

vectors.forEach(function(vector){
    vector.removeAllFeatures();
});
```